# Environment with a given number n of empty pages at the end works for n > 0, but fails for n = 0

Tags: environments, labels

I'd like to construct an exam environment that allows to add a number of empty
pages at the end of each exam. Each exam consists of a) a cover page, b) main
pages with problems and c) empty pages at the end (their number is specified as
argument of the exam environment). The cover page should show the number of
pages of the exam (including the empty pages at the end). As such, I put a label
on the cover page and one at the end of each exam environment (the difference
plus 1 is then the number of pages). This all works fine (see Exam 1 below) as
long as there is a positive number of empty pages at the end of each
exam. However, if I choose 0 such pages (see Exam 2 below), the number of pages
of the exam is 0 (although it should be at least 0, counting the cover page and
at least one page of exam problems). Why?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcommand\numberOfPages[1]{\edef\tmp{\number\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{end:page:#1}-\getpagerefnumber{start:page:#1}+1\relax}\tmp}% command for counting the number of pages of an exam

% Counters for the exam environment
\newcounter{examEnvCounter}% counts how often the environment 'exam' was called
\setcounter{examEnvCounter}{0}% initialize
\newcounter{numEmptyPages}% counter for the number of empty pages at the end of each exam

% Environment exam
\newenvironment{exam}[1]{% the argument is the number of empty pages at the end of the exam
  % Counters
  \setcounter{page}{1}% set page number to 1
  \stepcounter{examEnvCounter}% increase counter which counts how many times the exam environment was called

  % Cover/first page
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \label{start:page:\number\value{examEnvCounter}}% define label for computing number or pages
  {\bfseries Exam~\number\value{examEnvCounter}}
  \par\bigskip
  Number of pages this exam covers (including this cover page): \numberOfPages{\number\value{examEnvCounter}}
  \clearpage

  % Subsequent exam pages should show "Page ... of <number of pages>"
  \renewcommand\pagemark{Page~\thepage~of~\numberOfPages{\number\value{examEnvCounter}}}
  \setcounter{numEmptyPages}{#1}% number of empty pages at the end
}{% Inserting the provided number of empty pages
  \ifnum\value{numEmptyPages} > 0% only enter the loop if we have at least one empty page
  \loop
  \clearpage% create empty page ...
  Extra page at the end of this exam for scratch work, additional answers, etc. % ... with some text
  \addtocounter{numEmptyPages}{-1}% decrease required (remaining) number of empty pages
  \ifnum\value{numEmptyPages} > 0
  \repeat
  \fi% \ifnum

  % Insert label at the end (to determine the number of pages of the exam)
  \label{end:page:\number\value{examEnvCounter}}\clearpage
}

\begin{document}
% Exam 1
\begin{exam}{1}% first call (with one empty page at the end => fine!)
  Some text as placeholder for an exam question.
  \clearpage
\end{exam}

% Exam 2
\begin{exam}{0}% second call (with no empty pages at the end => doesn't determine the number of pages correctly)
  Some text as placeholder for an exam question.
  \clearpage
\end{exam}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are not shipping out the page with the end label, and so it ends in the nirwana.

Comment: Hi Ulrike, thanks a lot for your help! Is there a workaround for that? I realized that creating one additional page makes it work again, but then there is this additional useless page there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the number of blank pages to issue, you can just set a label at the end of the exam text and add the number of blank pages.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcommand\numberOfPages[2]{%
  \the\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{end:page:#1}+#2\relax
}

% Counters for the exam environment
\newcounter{examEnvCounter}% counts how often the environment 'exam' was called
\newcounter{numEmptyPages}% counter for the number of empty pages at the end of each exam

% Environment exam
\newenvironment{exam}[1]{% the argument is the number of empty pages at the end of the exam
  \clearpage
  % Counters
  % set page number to 1
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
  % increase counter which counts how many times the exam environment was called
  \stepcounter{examEnvCounter}
  \setcounter{numEmptyPages}{#1}% number of empty pages at the end
  %
  % Cover/first page
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \noindent\textbf{Exam~\theexamEnvCounter}%
  \par\bigskip
  Number of pages this exam covers (including this cover page):
  \numberOfPages{\theexamEnvCounter}{#1}%
  \clearpage
  % Subsequent exam pages should show "Page ... of <number of pages>"
  \renewcommand\pagemark{Page~\thepage~of~\numberOfPages{\theexamEnvCounter}{#1}}%
}{%
  % label
  \label{end:page:\theexamEnvCounter}%
  \clearpage
% Inserting the provided number of empty pages
  \ifnum\value{numEmptyPages} > 0% only enter the loop if we have at least one empty page
    \loop
    Extra page at the end of this exam for scratch work, additional answers, etc.
    \clearpage% create empty page ...
    \addtocounter{numEmptyPages}{-1}% decrease required (remaining) number of empty pages
    \ifnum\value{numEmptyPages} > 0
    \repeat
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

% Exam 1
\begin{exam}{1}
  Some text as placeholder for an exam question.
\end{exam}

% Exam 2
\begin{exam}{0}
  Some text as placeholder for an exam question.
  \clearpage
  This exam has two pages, but no additional blank page
\end{exam}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For producing the picture I used A6 paper.

Comment: ... thanks a lot, egreg. That's a nice idea to approach it!